# Стоит ли выносить различные методы обработки нажатий в другой класс, который не относится к классу Activity?

Tags: java, android, ооп

Из опыта разработки на java, я усвоил, что целесообразнее будет для каждого действия делать свой отдельный класс, дабы следовать канонам ООП. Но вот теперь, начав изучать Android, у меня возник вопрос. А стоит ли так делать в Android-разработке? Ведь тут и так для каждой Activity создается свой класс, но все же, когда в Activity очень много различных кнопок, полей и т.д., код в ней выглядит очень большим и его становится неудобно читать. Хотелось бы услышать мнение знающих людей по этому поводу.

Comment: Нет, этого делать не нужно. Активити - контроллер виджетов на экране, ее назначение в том и состоит, чтобы обрабатывать реакции на виджеты

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Из опыта разработки на java, я усвоил, что целесообразнее будет для каждого действия делать свой отдельный класс

Иногда это целесообразно, иногда – избыточно. Абстрактно очень сложно что-то сказать, все зависит от конкретной ситуации.

> А стоит ли так делать в Android-разработке?

Опять же – все зависит от конкретного случая.

> но все же, когда в Activity очень много различных кнопок, полей и т.д., код в ней выглядит очень большим и его становится неудобно читать.

Манипуляции с какими-либо `View`-объектами не стоит выносить куда-то за пределы активити, непосредственно к которой они относятся – это, как минимум усложняет чтение кода и чревато *утечками памяти*.

Для *настройки* представлений можете добавить в активити метод `void configViews()`, в котором сгруппировать все действия по *настройке* этих виджетов.

Манипуляции с какими-либо **не** `View`-объектами можно вынести в отдельный класс, следуя концепции ООП, а вот нужно это или нет – зависит от конкретной ситуации.